# AngularJs function form is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I am trying to create a form that can change a username of a user
This is my html code:

```
<div ng-controller="manageProfile" >
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Display Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="user.currentName" placeholder="Display Name">
        </div>
        <button ng-click="changeName()">Change Username</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is my AngularJs Code

```
var profile = angular.module('getUserInfo', ['ngParse']);
profile.controller('manageProfile', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.changeName = function(form) {
        var user = Parse.User.current();
        user.setUsername(form.currentName);
        user.save(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("fail");
            }
        });
     };
}]);
```

When I click the `Change Username` button, it wil give me `Error: form is undefined`. What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: changeName function takes a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The param for a click event is "$event". In html code you did not passed any param to changeName function.
You can use ng-model to get value from the form after assigned ng-model in html.

```
 $scope.changeName = function() {
        var user = Parse.User.current();
        user.setUsername($scope.user.currentName);
        user.save(null, {
            success: function(user) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("fail");
            }
        });
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you form needs a name in order to Angular to pick it up.

```
<form name="myForm" />
```

Then from your controller you can access it by-

```
var form = $scope.myForm;
```